# Exercício de árvore genealógica

Tags: prolog

Tenho que criar uma relação de tio de acordo com a árvore genealógica à seguir:
[image: Árvore Genealógica]

Já tenho o seguinte código:

```
mãe(ana, eva).
mãe(eva, noé).
mãe(bia, raí).
mãe(bia, clô).
mãe(bia, ary).
mãe(lia, gal).
pai(ivo, eva).
pai(raí, noé).
pai(gil, raí).
pai(gil, clô).
pai(gil, ary).
pai(ary, gal).
mulher(ana).
mulher(eva).
mulher(bia).
mulher(clô).
mulher(lia).
mulher(gal).
homem(ivo).
homem(raí).
homem(noé).
homem(gil).
homem(ary).
gerou(ana, eva).
gerou(ivo, eva).
gerou(eva, noé).
gerou(raí, noé).
gerou(bia, raí).
gerou(bia, clô).
gerou(bia, ary).
gerou(gil, raí).
gerou(gil, clô).
gerou(gil, ary).
gerou(ary, gal).
gerou(lia, gal).
avô(X, Y) :- pai(X, Z), pai(Z, Y); pai(X, Z), mãe(Z, Y).
avó(X, Y) :- mãe(X, Z), mãe(Z, Y); mãe(X, Z), pai(Z, Y).


filho(X, Y) :- gerou(Y, X), homem(X).
filha(X, Y) :- gerou(Y, X), mulher(X).

/* irmãos(raí, clô).
irmãos(clô, raí).
irmãos(ary, clô).
irmãos(ary, raí).
irmãos(clô, ary).
irmãos(raí, ary). */
```

No exercício que estou fazendo, não pede para criar a relação irmãos, mas eu posso usá-la para criar a relação tio? Senão, quais relações eu devo usar? Obrigado e perdão caso eu não tenha me expressado corretamente.

Comment: Não conheço prolog. Sobre a relação de irmão é automática, quando compartilhar pai, mãe ou ambos. Se existe relacao de irmão com o genitor de um filho, logo é tio

Comment: Bem pensado sobre a relação de irmão, poderia ter criado uma regra para defini-la.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se duas pessoas tem a mesma mãe, logo são irmãos. O caminho mais fácil seria criar a relação irmão e irmã:

```
irmao(X,Y) :- gerou(Z,X), gerou(Z,Y), homem(X)
irma(X,Y) :- gerou(Z,X), gerou(Z,Y), mulher(X)
```

Finalmente, a relação *tio* seria:

```
tio(X,Y) :- irmao(X,Z), pai(Z,Y); irma(Z, X), mae(Z, Y)
```

Agora se criar a relação irmão e irmã não é permitido, é possível resolver com a regra abaixo:

```
tio(X,Y) :- homem(X), gerou(M, X), gerou(M, I), pai(I,Y); 
            homem(X), gerou(M, X), gerou(M, I), mae(I,Y)
```

Comment: Valeu cara. Ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Para simplificar, vou ignorar as questoes de masculino/feminino.

Convem evitar que:

- todos sejam irmãos de si próprios
- os pais sejam tios de seus filhos

Para tal juntei uma condição `X ≠ Y` neste caso codificada como `X \== Y`

```
irmao(X,Y) :- gerou(PAI,X), gerou(PAI,Y), X \== Y.    
tio(T,Y)   :- gerou(AVO, T), gerou(AVO, PAI), gerou(PAI,Y), T \== PAI.
```

Analogamente podemos remover muitos factos elementares redundantes de juntarmos
mais duas regras:

```
mulher(A):-  mae(A,_).
homem(A) :- pai(A,_).
```